# Most memory-efficient way to split a variable sized chunks?

Tags: php, split, fread

Is there a way to do something like an `fread`, but on a variable?
That is, I want to "read" another in-memory variable 1MB at a time.

That way I could have something like this:

```
$data = ... ; // 10MB of data

$handle = fopen($data, "rb"); // Need something instead of fopen here

while (!feof($handle))
{
    $chunk = fread($handle, 1048576); // Want to read 1MB at a time

    doSomethingWithChunk($chunk);
}

fclose($handle);
```

I have a large binary file loaded into memory, about 10MB. I'd like to split it into an array of 1MB chunks. I don't need all 1MB chunks in memory at once, so I think I could do something like the above more efficiently than just using PHP's built-in [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to sequentially 'read' a string that's already loaded into memory; it's not really more efficient to split it up. The overhead of multiple variables will use more memory than a single one as well. Ideally you would load the string into a stream, but PHP doesn't really have a string stream.

If you just want to deal with the string in chunks, you can just loop over substrings of it:

```
$data;
$pointer = 0, $size = strlen($data);

$chunkSize = 1048576;
while ($pointer < $size)
{
    $chunk = substr($data, $pointer, $chunkSize);
    doSomethingWithChunk($chunk);
    $pointer += $chunkSize;
}
```

I'm not sure how PHP handles large strings internally, but according to the [string documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), a string can only be "as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)". If your file is about 10MB, it shouldn't be a problem for PHP.

Another option (probably the better option) is to load `$data` into a [memory or temporary stream](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptios). If you want to spare the environment from excessive memory, you can use the `php://temp` stream wrapper, where some of the data is stored in a temporary file if it exceeds 2MB. Just load the string into the stream as soon as possible to conserve memory, and then you can use the file stream functions on it.

```
$dataStream = fopen("php://temp", "w+b");
fwrite($dataStream, funcThatGetsData()); // try not to put data into a variable to save memory

while (!feof($dataStream))
{
    $chunk = fread($dataStream, 1048576); // want to read 1MB at a time
    doSomethingWithChunk($chunk);
}

fclose($dataStream);
```

If you get `$data` from another function you could pass around `$dataStream` instead. If you must have `$data` in a string beforehand, be sure to call `unset()` on it to free the memory:

```
$data = getData(); // string from some other function
$dataStream = fopen("php://temp", "w+b");
fwrite($dataStream, $data);
unset($data); // free 10MB of memory!
...
```

If you want to keep it all in memory you can use `php://memory`, but you might as well just use a string in that case.

Comment: Both methods worked. Unfortunately, I benchmarked both methods and they are actually *slower* than str_split - so I'll just keep the code the way it is. :) Thank you for the very thorough answer though!

FYI for future reference, the `php://memory` orders of magnitude slower slower than `str_split`, whereas the `substr` method only is almost neck & neck w/ `str_split`. However, `str_split` is just barely faster - and it's a lot easier to read/maintain.

End result: Leave everything alone!

Comment: @DOOManiac: I imagined the virtual streams would be slower - the idea behind using `php://temp` is that it is much more *memory* efficient. Even if it stores it all in memory, I bet it is using raw C byte arrays rather than the more convenient but greater memory-consuming `$string`. Using a stream and reading by chunks prevents your memory from spiking really high. If that's not your goal, then `str_split` probably is your best bet. ;)

Comment: My goal is speed, pure and simple. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use like;

```
$handle = @fopen("path_to_your_file", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 1024)) !== false) {
        doSomethingWithChunk($buffer );
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: I would second this answer with blind eyes :)

Comment: I don't want to read the file from disk (again). It's already read into memory by the time it gets here. Plus it may not be from disk at all - it could be from a database read or other input. So sorry, this answer has nothing to do with what I need...

Comment: If you put it on memory already, you need to allocate it in memory efficiently. For example you need to use array, and then you need to get 100 by 100 from that array. You cannot use fopen, fread, etc... they are file operation functions