# Alternatives to Regex for extracting information from a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempt to extract information from a string, which will always be in the same format.

The format will always be:

```
To:
                     Name here
Date:
                     26/08/2014 14:52
Order Number:
                     123456
Service Required:
                     Plumbing
Service Response:
                     48 Hour
Service Limit:
                     110.00

123 TEST ROAD
LEEDS
LS1 1HL

Contact:
                     Mr J Smith - 0777 123456
Telephone:
                     01921 123456

Work Details:

Notes here etc
```

I have tried exploding the string by spaces and looping through the array but I cannot structure it in such a way that I receive the information.

E.g: I try to retrieve **"Name here"** from *after* **"To:"** without also retrieving "Date: etc..", the eventual idea is to create variables for each bit of information so i can enter it into a database.

Any help/suggestions/idea's are really welcome.

thanks for reading

Comment: Not using regex is harder. Its harder to account for variability within the form. Sure you don't want to use regex?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, its not that I don't want to regex but simply right now I can't manage the complexity of it, I was asking to see if there was an easier to accomplish this particular task without regex. I have been attempting to use http://www.regexr.com/ to build the expression but with honestly confusing results.

My idea was to create an expression that finds a string after "to:" but before "date:" and repeat this for each variable, but all attempts have failed miserably haha.

Comment: hey @sln, why are you fighting in defense of Regex? If the guy is asking for an altenative solution to regex, you can give a proper answer, or sumply turn page. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex easily.

If you use this regex, you can get the `name here`:

```
To:\s+(.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC6qG1/1)**

[image]

The idea of this regex is to look for the `key` you want to look for and fetch the value. For instance, above regex looks for `To:` whitespaces and store in a capturing group the content.

You just need to change `To` for whatever you want, if you modify it to `Date` you will get the date.

[image]

As a note, this only works with single line values.

The code to implement this regex in php is very straightforward, like this:

```
$re = "/To:\\s+(.*)/";
$str = "YOUR STRING HERE";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

On the other hand, below data follows a different pattern:

```
123 TEST ROAD
LEEDS
LS1 1HL
```

You'd need a different regex pattern too, so to fetch that information you could use:

```
^(\w+[\w\s]+)(?!:)$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC6qG1/2)**

Comment: I noticed a downvote, any comment to improve the answer? Downvotes without comment are such unuseful...

Comment: Hi, just wanted you to know, I did not down vote you, when I saw the down vote I upvoted you myself, this answer seems to work, Im just trying it with a few values before I mark accepted, I must say my attempts were a complete mess compared to these.

Comment: Thanks @Pheonix2105 glad to help you. I gave you back the favour, don't understand why people downvote without explanation.

Comment: Intersting approach. Do I see a  pitfall with not normalized data? Agree with downvote without clarification.

Comment: Also, as someone else stated here, "the question clearly says alternatives to regular expressions and you give a regex?" :)

Comment: @augusto OP tagged the question with regex, also pointed that we wanted an alternative to regex since he doesn't have full understand of them. The idea of providing answers (working answers indeed) is to help the community. If you read about SO you can find that answers not always provide the kind of solution some one expect, but helps to provide different solutions for the same problem. If you downvoted you should think about moving to other community. Bear in mind that I haven't downvoted you

Comment: before this, I always felt comfortable here, @Fede. As I never read such aggressive words. EOS.

Comment: @augusto don't misunderstand my comment. I'm not aggressive at all and I don't want to be agressive, so.. I'm sorry if my comment sounded as it. As I commented before SO is a community with people willing to help other people, that's why I don't support downvotes meaning "I don't like this answer". But insist, sorry if I thought I was aggressive with you.

Comment: I think an answer that does not do what the question says just make it very difficult for people to find wjat they are looking for (even though it could be helpful somewhere else).

Comment: `Alternatives to Regex` is a very general phrase.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a regex, since you are looking for the first field content, you can use a double explode:

```
$firstfield= trim(explode("\n",explode(':', $data, 3)[1])[1]);

var_dump($firstfield);
```

Otherwise to obtain fields and values with a regex, you can use this:

```
$pattern = '~^(\w+(?: \w+)*):\s*(.+?)\s*(?=(?1):|\z)~ms';

preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($m as $v) {
    $results[$v[1]] = $v[2];
}

echo $results['To'];
```

Comment: I'm afraid exploiding by ":" will break data. You need flexibility here.

Answer (score 0):

**Later update (the work done)**

Here's the fully working script. I guess you'll appreciate here how flexible it is!

```
$s = "To:
          Name here
Date:
          26/08/2014 14:52
Order Number:
          123456
Service Required:
          Plumbing
Service Response:
          48 Hour
Service Limit:
          110.00

123 TEST ROAD
LEEDS
LS1 1HL

Contact:
          Mr J Smith - 0777 123456
Telephone:
          01921 123456

Work Details:

Notes here etc ";


$a = Array(
  Array("To:", "Date:" ),
  Array("Date:", "Order Number:" ),
  Array("Order Number:", "Service Required:" ),
  Array("Service Limit:", 'Contact:' ),
  //etc
);  

foreach ($a as $anchors)  {
  $t = explode ($anchors[0], " ".$s );
  $t = explode ($anchors[1], $t[1]  );
  $r = trim($t[0]);
  echo $anchors[0] ." [". $r ."]\n"  ;
}
```

Which will produce:

```
augusto@cubo:~/Documents$ php script.php
To: [Name here]
Date: [26/08/2014 14:52]
Order Number: [123456]
Service Limit: [110.00

123 TEST ROAD
LEEDS
LS1 1HL]
```

**Older answer (the concept)**
Seems to be not too difficilt.

You have many good anchors to work on! explode() will be a good friend.

```
$tmp = explode ('anchor-before', $string  );
$tmp = explode ('anchor-after', $tmp[1]) ;
$res = trim($tmp[0]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I have tried explode("\s") and preg_split('/\s+/') both return arrays with the exploded words correctly but iterating over this and only extracting "Name here" after "To:" but before "Date:" and "26/08/2014 14:52" after "Date:" but before "Order Number:"has proven difficult.

Comment: not sure I get your steps. Code in reply will do the job.

Comment: @Pheonix2105, hope you'll be abel to take advantage from the fully working code above. Still, can't get the reason people downvoted this?

Comment: That would be a lot of explosions in a string with 40,000 records. Any solutions other than this particular explode example ?

Comment: You'd better open a new question for your performance concern, @sln (don't want to go out of scope). Please let me know if I can give more help here (and if you are happy applying my solution of course)

Comment: That's not a performance issue, that would hang your computer.

Comment: I see, @sln. Handling large data is a differet issue (it would with php, rexex, or whatever). Once your php.ini is optimised for this task, I guess you should split your large data in pieces, keeping memory usage as low as possible. [ see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121037/most-memory-efficient-way-to-split-a-variable-sized-chunks ]. I hope you'll appreciate my running script exposed above, anyway. Please do ask if I can give more help.

Comment: Explosion fails because it splits on keywords that can be in the field data, and because there is no way to delimit the start of records, or fail records if they don't have the proper alignment. There no validation, no self correction, no error catching mechanism. All in all, its even more primitive than split, and is not viable for record parsing.

Comment: On my side, everything is running fine. No error, no failures, proven by previous experience also. I guess you may past here your failure, eventually wearing best smile you have ;). Question title seems to be honored, to me. After that, I can't help you any further. Thanks a lot for your time and good luck!

Comment: There is nothing that explode() does except splits a string on a given literal. It doesn't matter where it is in the string, it's not anchored, nor positionally variable from an anchor. There is no beginning nor end, its continuous and open-ended. Add to that the possibility of field data containing field names, it works out to be the worst possible way to parse fields/variable data records.

Comment: I do see you point, @sln. Right now I see your previous comment above as well. So, no surprise with your being that negative. I can't assist you any further. If are able to provide a better answer to the question, please do post here. It would be appreciated from the Community. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A regex is not that difficult. Try this one.

```
 # '~(?msi)^To:\s*(.*?)\s*^Date:\s*(.*?)\s*^Order\ Number:\s*(.*?)\s*^Service\ Required:\s*(.*?)\s*^Service\ Response:\s*(.*?)\s*^Service\ Limit:\s*(.*?)\s*^Contact:\s*(.*?)\s*^Telephone:\s*(.*?)\s*^Work\ Details:\s*(.*?)\s*~'

 (?msi)
 ^ To: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (1)
 \s* 
 ^ Date: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (2)
 \s* 
 ^ Order\ Number: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (3)
 \s* 
 ^ Service\ Required: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (4)
 \s* 
 ^ Service\ Response: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (5)
 \s* 
 ^ Service\ Limit: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (6)
 \s* 
 ^ Contact: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (7)
 \s* 
 ^ Telephone: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (8)
 \s* 
 ^ Work\ Details: \s* 
 ( .*? )                            # (9)
 \s*
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 26 , len 9 ) 
Name here  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 65 , len 16 ) 
26/08/2014 14:52  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 119 , len 6 ) 
123456  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 167 , len 8 ) 
Plumbing  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 217 , len 7 ) 
48 Hour  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 263 , len 39 ) 
110.00

123 TEST ROAD
LEEDS
LS1 1HL  
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 337 , len 24 ) 
Mr J Smith - 0777 123456  
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 396 , len 12 ) 
01921 123456  
 **  Grp 9 -  ( pos 427 , len 0 )  EMPTY
```

Comment: the question clearly says alternatives to regular expressions and you give a regex? :)

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark - The question is clearly tagged `regex` not `regex alternative`. In a reply to a clarification, the OP states he can't use regex because he is not knowledgeable of regex. He has a variable record form which regex handles better than any alternative. He could just inject code that extracts these fields into the code that creates the string. I assume he can't do that, so I would have to assume this is from a log file of sequential records. Instead of criticism, post your alternative solution.

Comment: My alternative solution is to remove the tag regex from the question or change the question because (other than the title being very clear), in the question he clearly states: " I am looking for alternative methods". So this does not answers the question but as you admit it answers a comment.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark - You know we try to actually help folks here. It appears this is a log file of many records. Exploding, a form of split() doesn't cut it. And, there really is no alternative string functions to do this task. That's why he put the regex tag there in the first place.

Comment: I think an answer that does not do what the question says just make it very difficult for people to find wjat they are looking for (even though it could be helpful somewhere else). I landed here because I  needed an alternative to regex as the question states and I ended up reading 3 different regex instead. Hoe is this useful to me or to anyone who lands here? They are very good pieces of code, but out of scope here. So I say change the question or cheange the answers, but they just don't go well together.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark - Most people ask questions when they are in need of help. SO is a plethora of alternative's offered on every single posted question. Alternative to regex are available, they are string function primatives, from which regex engines are built on. Did you just google `Alternative to regex` ? You must have gotten millions of results, why did you pick this one? There is _NO_ easy regex alternative to parse variable form records without using regex. Its just simply a fact.

Comment: I am not saying your answer is not pretty, I am just saying that this question is not the place. open another question for that answer or if you want to help the poor guy write him a private message. this is a community site and if a question is duplicated or not good enough for the others, it gets deleted. So why an answer like this (that is not useful to the community nor to the question) be here at all?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark - The OP accepted a regex solution because he saw how easily it could be done. If that he accepted it is a problem contact a moderator. The lesson of this post, for you or the community is that multiple variable form records can't be parsed with anything other than regex. So the answer in this case, until proven otherwise is there is _no alternative to regex_.